# How to include parent project in ant build.xml

Tags: android, ant, junit

I have testproject which extends AndroidTestCase. Now these test case runs on project1 and project2. These project1 and project2 are included in java build path.It runs in eclipse but not when i run ant's build.xml run target. It gives compilation error. Anyone knows how to get rid from this?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Note that Google engineers have been telling developers to move off of Ant and onto Gradle for ~15 months.

Comment: @CommonsWare- Yes i know.. but need to do this using ant only.

Comment: Can anybody tell me how to do this..(without generating jar files for parent project)

Comment: Generally speaking, you need to make sure the classpath your ant build is using contains the generated artifacts (eg. Jars) of the projects it depends on.  So if project1 and project2 both depend on AndroidTestCase, you need to figure out what jar that class lives in, and make sure your ant build can find it.

Comment: @David- The class extends AndroidTestCase require parent project jars then only it  will get compile. What need is - Not to generate jar and use javabuild path in ant script. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking for.  If you want your classes in project1 and project2 build against the classes in the parent, then the classes in the parent _have_ to exist, either in the form of .class files you can reference, or in .jar files you can add to the classpath.  I suppose it might be possible to build a fileset of all the .java source files from your parent and child projects and just compile it all in one go, but that's contrary to a number of development best practices.